# How to recover three successive rotations of a vector

Tags: vector-spaces, 3d, rotations

I have a vector, which I rotated with respect to $x$, $y$ and $z$ axes, respectively.

Now I want to recover this operation, that means I want to bring it to the previous position by rotating it with $-\theta$, $-\alpha$ and $-\beta$, where $\theta$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the amounts of initial rotation, in radians/degrees.

I tried to do it by computing the dot product of this vector with axis vectors ($(1,0,0)$ for $x$-axis, $(0,1,0)$ for $y$-axis and $(0,0,1)$ for $z$-axis).

However, this did not produce the right result possibly because It was rotated in 3d, thus the dot product was resulting in a different value that it should be.

What I should do in order to perform this operation? Thanks.

Comment: do you mean you rotated using [Euler angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles)? or did you rotate around the fixed axes?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Do you mean that you know the position $x$ of your point before rotating, the position $x'$ of the point after rotating, and then you want to find the angles $\theta,\alpha,\beta$ such that $x'$ gets send back to $x$? Or do you already know $\theta, \alpha,\beta$ and you just want to know how to use these to create a rotation that sends $x'$ back to $x$?

Comment: @Lieven The latter one. I know $\theta$,$\alpha$ and $\beta$, and I want to find the rotation that sends $x'$ back to $x$.

Comment: @nbubis using Euler angles.

Comment: As @nbubis mentioned, Euler angles is what you are looking for.

Comment: don't forget to reverse the order (if your last rotation was around $z$ your first reverse one should be around $z$ with the sign changed).

Answer (score 0):

If you used Euler angles, simply multiply your vector by the rotation matrices in reverse order. If you used $\alpha$ around $\hat{x}$, then $\beta$ around $\hat{y}$, and finally $\gamma$ around $\hat{z}$ to get at a vector $v$, then the original vector $v_0$ is given by:
$$v_0 = Z(-\gamma)Y(-\beta)X(-\alpha)v$$ 
Where $X,Y,Z$ are the rotation matrices.

Comment: More at [Rotation Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions).